# adding and counting numbers and texts in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I need to add the following numbers including the X”s and the M”s, which will have the assigned value of 10 and 0, respectively.  That is, in C6 to L6 and the result should be in M6.  But also need to count the X’s (as text) and add them up in N6.

It should all add up to a total of 79, with two X’s.
Thanks for answering.

I am trying to build an excel chart for accounting shooter’s scores.  Ten shots @ 10 points each for a total of 100 points.  Now, every bull’s eye is marked as an X, in the target paper.  The X’s count as 10 points each.  Also the M’s, which are misses, have a value of zero.  So, if a shooter gets— 3-X’s; 5-10’s and 2-M’s (misses), the total will be: 80 points out of 100 total.

Now, I need to set it up in excel in order for the competitors know their total points and the X’s, because in case of a tie, the number of X’s are to decide.  That is, Total number of points and total number of X’s in separate columns.

I appreciate your help.
JP

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! As is, your question is really unclear. It would help a lot if you included some sample data in your question. You can [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1011123/edit) your question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is this (if you had scores in C6 thru L6):

M6  `=SUM(C5:L6)+(COUNTIF(C5:L6,"X")*10)`

N6  `=REPT("X",COUNTIF(C5:L6,"X"))`